# How to Prevent Post back of Menu Control that is on Master Page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, menu, master-pages, postback

I have created Dynamic Menu from Database of SQLServer2008 which is loaded on page load and accordingly the menus are displayed. Problem is when i click any MenuItem of the menu from Content Page the Menu Control also loads again from the DataBase which i want to avoid the PostBack and prevent the Hit to DataBase for loading the menu.

In .master

```
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div id="navbar" runat="server">
           &nbsp;&nbsp; 
                    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" Orientation="horizontal" RenderingMode="List" runat="server"
                        DynamicHorizontalOffset="0" OnMenuItemClick="Menu1_MenuItemClick">
                        <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="10px" />
                    </asp:Menu>
            </div>
             <br />
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                   Content here....
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
     </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

In .master.cs file

```
public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{

    static string  conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    int empID = 0;
    int recAffect = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            populateMenuItem();

        }
    }
}
```

populateMenuItem() is a method from where the Menu is Bind from SQLServerDB table called MenuMaster.

When i click any MenuItem the page is redirected. This works fine. **Just i want to AVOID the LOADING OF MENU afte EACH LOADING OF CONTENT PAGE!**
Help Appreciated!
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Use some temporary storage location like Cache or Session and load from it.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is once the application loads, I create the menu and load it into memory, and then query the data from memory instead.  So I create a class like:

```
public class SiteMap
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Url { get; set; }
   public List<SiteMap> Items { get; set; }
}
```

During the starting up of your application, query from database and build a collection of SiteMap objects, and store this in a static reference, like:

```
public static class SiteMapStore
{
   private static List<SiteMap> _entries = null;


  public static List<SiteMap> Entries
  {
    get { return _entries; }
    set
    {
       if (_entries == value) 
         return;
       lock(typeof(SiteMapStore))
       {
            if (_entries != value) 
               _entries = value;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Using the SiteMapStore, you can then always refer to this when building the menu.  Storing the results in an object and globally will be much faster.

Comment: Thanks @Brian Mains for replying! But i am using the Menu Control and not the sitemap and populating to DataTable in Site.Master.cs page. Is their any way to store this data in to CACHE and access accordingly..! for generation menus..!

Comment: That's what I'm talking about; you pull from the database once, build a collection of SiteMap objects, and store that statically.  Your application then only pulls from the database once only.  This is an approach to caching the menu.

Comment: But these menus are different according to user logged in and with each page different Access level for different users.

Comment: You could have properties on the SiteMap class that contain this information, and show/hide certain site map items depending on these permissions.